# How to divide the path into several segments?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I need to divide the *Path* into several sections. For example, a Path has a **dashArray** parameter that specifies the length of the dash and length of the gap. I need to get one or more paths that match only the dashes. That is, I need to get a path like this

[image: path like this, but withoud dashArray]

but without **dashArray** attribute. How can I do this using paper.js or some other library?

Comment: i've down voted this nice question by mistake some time ago and now I can't reupvote. Apologies. This is a nice q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. PaperJS have a method *Path.getPointAt(offset)* Here offset - is ofsset in pixels from start of path. I maked [simple sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)