# How can I get a segment of a Path between two points using paper.js?

Tags: javascript, drawing, paperjs

I have a *Path* that intersects with another *Path*. Paper.js can give me points of intersection of these paths. Next, I need to get a segment of one path from one point of intersection to another. Example on the picture:

[image]

How can I get it using paper.js?

Comment: It's not a direct solution of this problem, but [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48538944/5284523) can help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Path.Line](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path-line-object) constructor to create a line between 2 points.

Here is a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/lVOxbsIwEP2VU5ZQFQWI1CVVJqZWHSp1BAbjXIuVYCPbkAHx7/UlDnFoUNtMvrv37HfvLudIsj1GWfRRouW7aBpxVVA8m0GhWQ0pcKF5hWat19IllUTQWFB0YpqOy6YOOUis4Z3ZXdJmJmcCgfs4SouaTpDBSWCdtJlpB9CsEEfjAU/za95YrUpcqkrpDGL3VkyVy8NzIGZbHbFTQ2cvp/vyXmLCK0eYtOwemgSvOHhMlfgWc1BGWKEkPOawIokwh00D8lK+0IKgpgzyBnhQLjSdsrBkBqIc8SUsTvpXW6VEby5b9D0NrluRlqSBDAnpXcJiQPAtNPNmzkTGSz91YBa2yu6G/LGmFv9cg7ajOxtwZwEaZeEK3IpIw+HnY/oGOzBC7Qedew9HHKoE7R3aGlH+7ox5dfe8ESXwhuLemU+t9n5UP5yx6rrLvpb+xR73J281srJdwyhbbS7f) drawing a line between 2 circles intersections.

```
// draw 2 circles
// one red
var redCircle = new Path.Circle({
    center     : view.center,
    radius     : 50,
    strokeColor: 'red'
});
// one blue
var blueCircle         = redCircle.clone();
blueCircle.strokeColor = 'blue';
blueCircle.position += [ 50, 0 ];

// get intersection points
var intersections = redCircle.getIntersections(blueCircle);
var point1        = intersections[ 0 ].point;
var point2        = intersections[ 1 ].point;

// draw a black circle at both intersections
var intersection1Circle = new Path.Circle({
    center     : point1,
    radius     : 5,
    strokeColor: 'black'
});
var intersection2Circle      = intersection1Circle.clone();
intersection2Circle.position = point2;

// draw a line between intersections
var intersectionsJoinLine = new Path.Line({
    from       : point1,
    to         : point2,
    strokeColor: 'black'
});
```